# xmppframework's didReceive presence is not working properly

Tags: swift, offline, xmppframework

I am using `func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive presence: XMPPPresence)` for managing online offline status.This function is working fine for one to one user but it will not working properly on multiple user.

for example I have 3 user A, B and C now the scenario is Online offline status is working fine for A to B and B to A as `func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive presence: XMPPPresence)` function is calling very well. but If C user check status of A or B then `func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive presence: XMPPPresence)` is not being called.

I won't be able to understand what is the issue. Here is my Code:

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive presence: XMPPPresence) {
    let presenceType = presence.type
    let myUsername = sender.myJID?.user

    print("myusername \(myUsername)")

    if let usr = presence.from?.user {

        print("didReceive :- \(presenceType)")
        print("didReceive usr :- \(usr)")

        if usr != myUsername {
            if presenceType == "available" {
                let dict: NSDictionary = ["presenceType":"1",
                                          "user_id":usr]
                if !APP_DELEGATE.arrPresentUser.contains(dict) {
                    APP_DELEGATE.arrPresentUser.add(dict)
                }
            } else {
                let pred : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "user_id = %@", usr)
                let approvalRequestArray =  APP_DELEGATE.arrPresentUser.filtered(using: pred) as NSArray
                if approvalRequestArray.count > 0 {
                    let dict = approvalRequestArray.object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary
                    APP_DELEGATE.arrPresentUser.remove(dict)
                }
            }
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("ReceivedUserStatus"), object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I had tried to use **@objc** also.**(`@objc func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive presence: XMPPPresence)`)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by adding following code

```
    let userReceiverJID = XMPPJID(string: "\(receiverJID)@\(CHATHOST)")

    APP_DELEGATE.xmppRoster.acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequest(from: userReceiverJID!, andAddToRoster: true)
    APP_DELEGATE.xmppRoster.subscribePresence(toUser: userReceiverJID!)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check presence of particular user, use this.

```
  let query = XMLElement(name: "query", xmlns: "jabber:iq:last")
  let iq = XMPPIQ(type: "get", to: "User's JID here", elementID: xmppStream.generateUUID, child: query)
  self.xmppStream.send(iq)
```

Get the presence in delegate method.

```
  func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive iq: XMPPIQ) -> Bool {
    if iq.isResultIQ {
      print(iq.from?.user)
      print(iq.lastActivitySeconds())
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me that what is xmppStream.generateUUID

Comment: @KD4, It is a method that XMPP provides and it generates a UUID and returns as a string. It is like unique id to identify some tag or attribute. You can use any other string also instead of this.

Comment: I am getting following error :  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:last"></query>, <error code="403" type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></forbidden></error>

Comment: This seems to be some kind of authentication error. Check your configuration and Rights. Also check if you are passing the full jid or not? Like userid@xmpp.something.in. If not, try to pass the full JID.